CMake clean build files of custom command
I have a CMake project where I need to call an external build tool (not make) with add_custom_command/add_custom_target to create a set of object files that other libs/executables depend on.
add_custom_target(build_external_lib_obj DEPENDS ${external_objects} ${external_libs})
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${external_objects} ${external_libs}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/external_build_tool target
)

Those object files are generated outside of the CMake build tree and (therefore?) not cleaned when I call
cmake --build .\build\ --target clean.
I want to clean those files via cmake as conveniently as possible.
I know a similar question exists already here, but as a comment states the accepted answer does not solve the original problem.
The accepted answer via set_property and ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES would work, but the build tree produced by the external build tool is  quite complex & distributed (therefore it would be inconvenient to track all produced files).
Additionally the external build tool already provides a clean step which tracks all the files.
Therefore extending the clean step with something like shown below would be preferable:
add_custom_target(external_clean COMMAND ./external_build_tool target_to_clean)
add_dependencies(clean external_clean)

This does not work as CMAKE does not find the clean target during configure:
[cmake] CMake Error at [PATH]/CMakeLists.txt:161 (add_dependencies):
[cmake]   Cannot add target-level dependencies to non-existent target "clean".

What I managed to do is create a custom target which first calls the regular clean, and then the external clean command:
add_custom_target(custom_clean
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target clean
    COMMAND external_build_tool target_to_clean
)

But this does not get called when I run a clean step via another tool, e.g. VS-Code.
Is my goal possible or do I have to use one of my workarounds?
